# A question on dynamic programming leetcode problem 221

Tags: python, dynamic-programming

I'm a beginner in Python. The following is my code for [leetcode 221](https://leetcode.com/problems/maximal-square/) (Maximal Square), it can only pass more than 30 test samples. It fails at  the matrix:  `M=[["1","0","1","0","0"],["1","0","1","1","1"],["1","1","1","1","1"],["1","0","0","1","0"]]`.

```
def maximalSquare(matrix):
    colleng=len(matrix)
    rowleng=len(matrix[0])
    maxsqlst=[]
    dp=[[0]*rowleng]*colleng
    for i in range(colleng):
        for j in range(rowleng):
            if matrix[i][j]=='1':
                if i==0 or j==0:
                    print('A',i,j,dp)
                    dp[i][j]=1
                    print('B',i,j,dp)
                else:
                    dp[i][j]=min(dp[i-1][j],dp[i][j-1],dp[i-1][j-1])+1
            print(i,j,dp)
        maxsqlst.append(max(dp[i]))

    return max(maxsqlst)**2
```

By inserting some `print()` command, I find that it goes wrong when i=j=0,

```
A 0 0 [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
B 0 0 [[1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0]].
```

Why does it make the first colume to be 1 instead of just dp[0][0]?

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: Thanks for your comment! When i=j=0, I hope it only set dp[0][0] to be 1, but it actually set the first colume of dp to 1. Why does that happen?@drum

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR**: Change your definition of `dp` from

`dp = [[0]*rowleng]*colleng`

to

`dp = [[0 for i in range(rowleng)] for j in range(colleng)]`

---

**Why?** In the first, you're creating a 2D list of *references to the same list*; in the second, you're creating a 2D list of *references to unique lists*.

(Technically, you could rewrite the 2nd lind as `dp = [[0]*rowleng for j in range(colleng)]` and get the same result.)

All that to say, when you declare `dp` to be a list of references to the *same list*, then when you change `dp[0][0]`, it "also changes" `dp[i][0]` for all `0 < i < len(dp)` -- because it's all the same list being referred to.

See e.g. [List of lists changes reflected across sublists unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly) for more info.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

In your function, you call this line:

```
dp[i][j]=1
```

This sets the item of i and j to 1, and if you notice the section where its called:

```
if matrix[i][j]=='1':
    if i==0 or j==0:
```

You will notice that both of those conditions are true in the cases you get 1, as this value is overriding whatever other values you've had, at least from what I see.

Remember that you are comparing with an **or** and not an **and**, so if either i or j were zero, not **both** necessarily, you will end up overriding the value, especially in locations where your matrix is equal to 1 (Here, your first column is all ones).